# Installing SSL Certificate On Node Server

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io

I created a self-signed certificate and installed it on apache as well as on node.js(port 3000). On localhost both `https://localhost` and `https://localhost:3000` works well.

So, I bought GoDaddy Standard SSL certificate and installed it on the server(`http://gatherify.com`). Now `https://gatherify.com` works well, but ssl on node isn't working. 
When I access `https://gatherify.com:3000` i get "The connection was interrupted".

I executed curl:

```
root@host [~]# curl -v -s -k https://gatherify.com:3000
* About to connect() to gatherify.com port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying 108.160.156.123... connected
* Connected to gatherify.com (108.160.156.123) port 3000 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* NSS error -5938
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

***UPDATE***
**SERVER SIDE :**

```
var io = require('socket.io'), 
    connect = require('connect'), 
    fs = require('fs'),

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('cert/server.key').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('cert/server.crt').toString();

var options = { 
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
};

var app = connect(options).use(connect.static('../htdocs/node/'));
app.listen(3000);
var server = io.listen(app);

server.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
console.log("Connected");
});
```

**CLIENT SIDE:**

```
<html> <head>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://gatherify.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">

var socket = io.connect('https://gatherify.com:3000', {secure:true}); 

</script>

</head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Port 3000 on that host does not use SSL, just normal HTTP, so accessing it with a https URL will fail.

Comment: do you have the `key` and `crt` certificate files?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Well, then how do i fix this problem?

Comment: @udidu Yes, I have those files...

Comment: your nodejs server working with expressjs?

Comment: @udidu i'm not using expressjs... I have updated the question with the server and client side code.

Comment: @user1918890 How about changing to something like `var app = require('https').createServer(options)`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it didn't make any difference too. Still i get Connection was interrupted

Comment: @user1918890 Did you remove `var app = connect(options).use(connect.static('../htdocs/node/'));` and replace it with the above line?

Comment: //var app = connect(options).use(connect.static('../htdocs/node/'));
var app = require('https').createServer(options);
app.listen(3000);
var server = io.listen(app);

this is what i did

Comment: @user1918890 I can't test myself atm, but have a look at `https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1011` for a sample.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run a node.js app on port 3000 with (behind) HTTPS, then you need to set up a proxy service on port 443 to proxy HTTPS requests to port 3000.

You didn't mention what server you have running on port 443 right now (is it Apache?) but you might want to

1. move that service to a new port (e.g. 4000), then run a [node http proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) on port 443 that handles HTTPS.
2. Then set up a subdomain for the node.js app that you have running on port 3000 (e.g. blah.gatherify.com).
3. Then, using [node http proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy), you will proxy all requests that are made to "gatherify.com" to port 4000, and all requests that are made to "blah.gatherify.com" to port 3000.

When all is set up properly, users can visit "https://gatherify.com" or "https://blah.gatherify.com" (without using :port numbers) and it'll all be secured with SSL. ;)

Comment: i did it the other way, i mean running proxy on apache and redirecting to node server. My web application in web browser is working over https perfectly (redirecting requests properly from apache to node securely) but our iOS and android APPs are not connecting to node.... plz guide me if you have any experience/info about it. Thanks :)

Comment: It should work the same on all devices that use HTTP. So, iOS, Android, Desktop, Laptop, they should all be able to connect. If it works in your desktop browser, I'm not sure why it wouldn't in your mobile browser, unless you have some user-agent redirection or something that is applying only to mobile user agents.

Answer (score 2):

## Install certificates Client Side (in Node.js)

If you need a node.js client to be able to recognize your self-assigned or cheaply-bought SSL certificates you can use [ssl-root-cas](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas), which is [available on npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ssl-root-cas).

```
'use strict';

var https = require('https')
  , cas
  ;

// This will add the well-known CAs
// to `https.globalAgent.options.ca`
require('ssl-root-cas').inject();

cas = https.globalAgent.options.ca;

cas.push(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ssl', '01-cheap-ssl-intermediary-a.pem')));
cas.push(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ssl', '02-cheap-ssl-intermediary-b.pem')));
cas.push(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ssl', '03-cheap-ssl-site.pem')));
```

This will make your certs available to the core `https` module as well as modules that depend on it such as `request` and `socket.io-client` without deleting the normal ssl certs (which is the default behavior for some odd reason).